# NuGet - Create a package with projectUrl from command line

Tags: nuget

Here's the command line I use to create a NuGet package:

```
nuget.exe pack something.csproj -OutputDirectory "\\some\directory" -Prop Configuration=Release
```

Is there a way to set the `projectUrl` element (or maybe any other [Metadata element](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference)) directly in the command line?

Answer (score -1):

How about something like the following:

```
nuget pack something.csproj foo.nuspec /p version=1.0.0.0;projectUrl="http://myurl.com/
```

[while nuspec would look like the following](https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/271117):

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<package xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'>
    <metadata>
        <id>Foo</d>
        <version>$version$</version>
        <authors>$authors$</authors>
        <description>Some description</description>
        <language>en-US</language>
        <licenseUrl>$licenseUrl$</licenseUrl>
        <projectUrl>$projectUrl$</projectUrl>
        <iconUrl>$iconUrl$</iconUrl>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <tags>some tags</tags>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency id='CodeContracts.Unofficial' version='$codeContractsVersion$'/>
        </dependencies>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        ......
    </files>
</package>
```

Comment: Interresting, but as I understand, this requires prior foo.nuspec existance, does it?

Comment: Yes it does require that foo.nuspec template file.

Comment: If provided response helped you to address the problem please mark it as the answer.

Comment: Sure. The question is in my pinned tabs, I just didn't have time to try your answer yet. I will soon.

Comment: @Jerther Provided response needs to be [marked]ticked to be considered as the answer.

Comment: I know. I'd like to try it first. Is there a time limit?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It does not work: nuget expects either a project a nuspec file, not both of them.